# Issue with MPMoviePlayerController playing an audio after a YouTube Video is opened in a Webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

In one View Controller **ViewController1**, I have tried to open a You tube video embedded in a UIWebview. It opens in the Movie Player window and then I use the "Done" button to come out of the movie player window. Again in another view controller **ViewController2** in the same application, I open a MPMoviePlayerController(MPMoviePlayerController *audioplayer) to play an audio file using streaming. However, it **remains in the paused state** on opening the player. Even when i call the method [audioplayer play], the application automatically sets back the playback state to paused (i rechecked and it is not done through my code).

But if i reopen the application and in view controller **ViewController2** i play the audio alone, then MPMoviePlayerController *audioplayer plays successfully.

Any idea what i might be doing wrong ?

This issue was found to be specific only to ios4.0. 
This issue doesnt occur in ios4.1 and above.

Comment: Since that's a relatively old version of iOS, and since all users of iOS 4.0 can upgrade to 4.2, would it be possible for you to require 4.2+?

Comment: Thanks Jess, yes the issue doesnt occur in devices with ios4.1+, but I was hoping to fix it for ios4.0 if it is possible. :)